# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL with retrofit

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, retrofit2

i'm trying to call an api in my application 
i've the following url template

> test-test.domainname.com/feeds/json/v3/attribute/attribute

i'm using retrofit 2 
but i get the following fatal exception

> Illegal URL: test-test.domainname.com

and this is my interface

```
public interface Iinterface{
    @GET("feeds/json/v3/attribute/"+attribute)
    Call<ArrayList<result>>getresult();
}
```

can someone help me with this problem ...

Comment: try that one url [link](http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/otherkey/othervalue)

Comment: the problem is with the '-' between 
test-test.domainname.com

Comment: test-test.domainname.com is running on localhost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

my base URL is here: `http://myapiname.azurewebservices.net`

and feed method is like that :

```
public interface Iinterface{
   @GET("/feeds/json/v3/attribute/"+attribute)
   Call<ArrayList<result>>getresult();
}
```

And working perfectly. Please add `http or https` and try again

Answer (score 7):

You do not have a protocol section.  Prepend `http://` or `https://` depending on which applies to your url --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://test-test.domainname.com")
        // ... other retrofit options
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
 my base url contained **space character**. (eg. `http://myapiname.azure webservices.net` )

I fixed this Error **by removing space in my base URL**.

> Illegal URL Exception in retrofit is triggered when your passed url is
>   not really existed or not fix with url standard.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I provided empty string to baseUrl() so because of this i was getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL` exception.